# Export all attributes and values of a user in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In "Active Directory Users and Computers" on Windows I have the ability to view a list of all attributes and their values.

I need to somehow export this list of values so that I have one column with the attribute name and one column with the value, just like in the picture.

[image]

I tried to do this with PowerShell

```
Get-ADUser smith -Properties * -value | Get-Member -MemberType property | Out-File "filename.csv"
```

But this just gives me a list of the attribute name, not the values.

How can I export everything in the attribute editor to a file with PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you ended up with that code, as it contains a lot of unnecessary additions that end up with you not having what you want.

All you need to do is

```
Get-ADUser smith -Properties * | Out-File "filename.csv"
```

Comment: This works, sort of. It does not include attributes with empty values though. Any chance to include them?

Comment: @Arete No because the way AD stores information means that the objects do not have those properties at all. The available options for properties is based on the AD schema for the `ObjectCategory` and `ObjectClass`, but properties that are not used are not stored against the object. You can get around this by reading information from the schema but that is going to be very complicated, or you can compile a list manually, if you really need all properties to show, as the list won't change unless there is a schema update.

Comment: how do you get multivalue properties?

Comment: That is a completely separate question but [this](https://www.millersystems.com/powershell-exporting-multi-valued-attributes-via-export-csv-cmdlet/) should give you the gist.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the MMC.

https://www.technipages.com/active-directory-schema-snap-in

1. Select the <kbd>Start</kbd> button, then type `CMD`.
2. Right-click on *Command Prompt* and select *Run as Administrator*.
3. Type the following, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   regsvr32 schmmgmt.dll
   ```
4. You should receive a message that registration succeeded.

Now, you should be able to add the snap-in using these steps:

1. Hold the <kbd>Windows</kbd> Key and press <kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run box.
2. Type `mmc`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The Microsoft Management Console opens.
3. Select *File* > *Add/Remove Snap-In*.
4. Select *Active Directory Schema*, then select <kbd>Add</kbd>.
   5-Select “OK“.

The Active Directory Schema option will now be available to use.

Then you select the folder inside that says `Class`, and you need to look for `User` class. Click on it, and it will show all of your attributes; then you only need to export the list doing right-click on the class.

NOTE: I don't know how to determine the writable attributes from this, but maybe you will figure when you will try it.

Comment: This helps to complete your question for the empty attributes